# Implementing mutexes for file writes

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, synchronization, mutex

I am trying to use mutexes to avoid multiple writes to the same thread inC/Cpp. Below is the flow of my program. I am confused as to where to include my lock and unlock code.

```
main() {
    spawn a worker thread
}
worker_thread() {
    read the input file name 
    read some content
    write the content to the given file name
}
```

Most of the implementation that I see, seem to have something like this:

```
main() {
    pthread_mutex_init(&myMutex;,0);
    *spawn a worker thread*
    pthread_join(thread1, 0);
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&myMutex;);
}
worker_thread() {
    read the input file name 
    read some content
    write the content to the given file name
}
```

What I want it something like this:

```
main() {
    spawn a worker thread
}
worker_thread() {
    read the input file name 
    read some content
    pthread_mutex_init(&myMutex;,0) --> for the given file?
    write the content to the given file name
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&myMutex;);
}
```

Any ideas to proceed much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: are you using c or c++?  If you're using c++11 onwards, don't use pthread_mutex but std::mutex

Comment: Are you trying to prevent the same file being written to in two different threads?

Comment: You need to decide what objects you're trying to protect from concurrent access by which threads or code paths. If you have something created and used only in one thread, then unless you actively share it with another thread, there's no need to protect access to that object.

Comment: *Why* are you trying to prevent simultaneous writes to your file?  Depending on your operating system, [there are ways to do atomic write operations to a file without locking at the application level](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pwrite.html).

Comment: Yes, I am trying to prevent concurrent writes to the same file by different threads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's fairly easy to create a wrapper for an iostream that ensures only one thread can write to the stream at a time. Unfortunately, almost as soon as you do so, you run into another problem. It ensures that only one thread can insert into the stream at a time, so you get defined behavior. If, however, you have something like:

thread 1: `sync_stream << a << b << c << '\n';`
thread 2: `sync_stream << x << y << z << '\n';`

What you wanted was either:

> abc
>   xyz

...or else:

> xyz
>   abc

Since they're in separate threads, it's fine for the order between them to vary, but a line of output from one thread should remain a single line of output. Something like:

> abxy
>   cz

...probably isn't desired or acceptable. To ensure against this, we really need *two* separate classes. One is a synchronized stream. The other is something to let us do some (more or less arbitrary) set of insertions into the stream as a single, indivisible "transaction". To do that, we can use a pair of classes like this:

```
class transaction {
    std::ostringstream buffer;
public:
    transaction(std::string const &s="") : buffer(s, std::ios::out | std::ios::ate) {}

    template <class T>
    transaction &operator<<(T const &t) {
        buffer << t;
        return *this;
    }

    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, transaction const &t) {
        return os << t.buffer.str();
    }
};

class sync_stream {
    std::ostream &out;
    std::mutex mutex;
public:
    sync_stream(std::ostream &sink) : out(sink) { }

    void operator<<(transaction const &t) {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> l(mutex);
        out << t;
    }    
};
```

Note that the `transaction` class supports chaining, but the `sync_stream` does not (and the only thing you can insert into it is a `transaction`). To use them, we do something like this:

```
for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
    threads[i] = std::thread([&]{ 
        for (int i=0; i<10; i++) 
            s << (transaction() << "Thread: " << std::this_thread::get_id() << "\n");
    });
```

This way, what a thread thinks of as a single output actually comes out as a single output, so our result might look like this:

> Thread: 140375947724544
>   Thread: 140376068564736
>   Thread: 140375964509952
>   Thread: 140375964509952
>   Thread: 140375972902656
>   Thread: 140375964509952

Of course, you'll get different thread IDs than I did, and the order of the lines is likely to vary--but each line will be written as a single, intact unit.

## Summary

The worker threads shouldn't work directly with the mutex at all. That should be automated, so the worker thread can focus on its work, and spend only a bare minimum of effort on the underlying mechanism necessary for it to do its job.