# cout not printing string and variable value consistently , misaligning the output

Tags: c++, newline, cout, flush

In the following code `threadCount` is one of 1,2,3,4 . But in the output, though the string part getting printed perfectly the num value getting missed randomly and it's getting appended after a few lines at times.

```
void *SPWork(void *t)
{

    int* threadC = (int*)t;
    int threadCount = *threadC;
    cout<<"\n Thread count" << threadCount << endl;
    cout << flush;
    long long int i, adjustedIterationCount;
    adjustedIterationCount = 100/(threadCount);
    for (i=0; i< adjustedIterationCount; i++)
    {
        i++ ;
    }
    pthread_exit((void*) t);
}
```

Output

```
......
.....
Thread count1
 Thread count1
 Thread count2
 Thread count1
 Thread count
 Thread count
 Thread count234
 .....
 .....
```

Notice in the last line thread value is 234. But that value will never be 234.In the previous 2 line that value didn't get appended and so 2,3 got added to this line.

I know it got to do with flush or appending "\n", tried many combinations. But still, the issue persists.

N.B. This is a worker method of a pthread, compiler flags are `"-g -Wall -O3 -lpthread"`

Comment: You can't have predictability when you have many threads all writing to the same IO device. Stuff is going to either need the be protected with a mutex or you have to learn to live with threads all cutting one another off.

Comment: this isn't thread safe. you're using `t` for all threads. and `i` is never used.

Comment: @codekaizer, not necessarily, each thread could be getting its *own* `t`. Without seeing the thread creation code, we don't know. In any case, there's nothing in the function that actually *changes* `t`.

Comment: "i is never used." yes some code stripped out to make it legible ...

Comment: [Near duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49155497/179910) (at least my answer there covers this question).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the standard streams are guaranteed to be thread-safe, there is no guarantee that the output won't be interleaved.  If you want to print to a standard stream from multiple threads in a predictable way, you will need to do some synchronization yourself:

```
std::mutex cout_mutex;

void *SPWork(void *t)
{
    //...
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(cout_mutex);
        std::cout << "\n Thread count" << threadCount << std::endl;
    }
    //...
}
```

Comment: This answer is slightly better than @paxdibalo's as it doesn't use unknown variable &myMutex

Comment: StackOverflow is full of awesome c/c++ programmers it seems. Work like a charm now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is no requirement that your calls to `cout` are an atomic operation. If you *need* them to be so, you can simply protect the code (just the output code) with a mutex.

In addition, injecting `std::endl` into the stream *already* flushes the data so there's little point in following that with a `std::flush`.

So, in its simplest form:

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&myMutex);
std::cout << "\n Thread count" << threadCount << std::endl;
pthread_mutex_unlock(&myMutex);
```

Note that, for recent C++ implementations, it's probably better to use `std::mutex` and `std::lock_guard` since they can guarantee correct clean up (see other answers for this). Since you have `pthread_exit()` in your code, I assume your limited to the POSIX threading model.

Comment: very interesting .. cout is Un-atomic. Never knew . If you can please provide a mutex code . This might be a pretty helpful answer to others coming to this question.